# What's the difference between "dir" and "ls"?

Tags: command, gnu

I have compared the man pages of `dir` and `ls` and they seem to be exactly the same. Both are part of GNU coreutils and "list directory contents".

The only difference I've seen so far is that `dir` doesn't colorize the output.

So why do two commands exist? Is there a difference I missed? Why would one prefer `dir` over `ls`?

Comment: One wouldn't! Ever!

Comment: [Difference between 'dir' and 'ls' terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/103913/253474)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would be inclined to think that `dir` is there just [for backwards compatibility](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103913/difference-between-dir-and-ls-terminal-commands).

From [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dir-invocation.html#dir-invocation):

> dir is equivalent to ls -C -b; that is, by default files are listed in columns, sorted vertically, and special characters are represented by backslash escape sequences.

By the way, `ls` doesn't colorize the output by default: this is because most distros alias `ls` to `ls --color=auto` in `/etc/profile.d`. For a test, type `unalias ls` then try `ls`: it will be colorless.

Comment: `dir` is not provided for backwards compatibility. Instead, `ls` works the way it does for backwards compatibility (and because lots of users want it to work that way), and `dir` is provided as an alternative, which the GNU developers consider generally preferable because its output is device-independent. See [4.5 Standards for Interfaces Generally](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#User-Interfaces) in the [GNU coding standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/) and [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/615946) to [that AU question](https://askubuntu.com/q/103913) for details.

Comment: i recommend  
Eliah Kagan answer

Answer (score 11):

`dir` isn't a Unix standard command (i.e. it is not specified by POSIX) but just a kind of alias/clone to provide some familiarity with Windows (DOS, CMD) users (and possibly VAX-VMS and other OSes where `dir` was used to list files).