# Alternatives of ls: dir and vdir

Tags: ls, coreutils

When I check the coreutils, I found that [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Directory-listing)

```
10 Directory listing
This chapter describes the ls command and its variants dir and vdir, which list information about files.

• ls invocation:        List directory contents.
• dir invocation:       Briefly ls.
• vdir invocation:      Verbosely ls.
• dircolors invocation:     Color setup for ls, etc.
```

`dir` and `vdir` is just appended to coreutils as an alternative of `ls`,

What's the purpose of such a setting.

I really initially believe that the coreutils are defined as less as possible.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. The second answer [in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103913/difference-between-dir-and-ls-terminal-commands) seems to explain the difference.

Comment: "GNU's Not Unix".  GNU utilities are _not_ minimalistic. They are primarily _convenient_.  This means that they generally break with the Unix tradition of "doing one thing only, and doing it well". Other examples of this is the `-printf` predicate to GNU `find` and and various other extra features crammed into various other utilities (features that are already handled by another set of utilities).

Comment: And we already have https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50377/ (and its duplicates) asking what the difference between them is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU is not completely minimal and dir is a common Microsoft command so it's aliased for convenience. Wiki is missing a full history but one might construct history from open-source archives..
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dir_(command)

Comment: The Unix minimal philosophy is about each command being minimal, not about minimal number of commands. However I see not whey there are 3 commands that do the same (or near same) thing.

Comment: "Aliased" is a really bad choice of words for what `dir` is in terms of the GNU coreutils. A default shell alias proper would have done as nicely as providing a separate command.

Comment: One would be better off constructing a history by reading books, wherein one will find that these two commands come from TOPS-20, not Microsoft, and that actual shell aliases used to be recommended for people used to the TOPS-20 commands.